# ##[error]Error: Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. handshake timeout

Tags: ssh, azure-devops

azure devops

release pipeline:

1 ssh task:  this task gets success

service connection: qadus

command: pwd, ls, mkdir hyd

2 copy over ssh:

source: drop/**

target:  /devops

##[error]Error: Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details.handshake timeout,

following error getting when copying files from build to linux machine

first task connection established,
second task failed, for this i have increased handshake time 20000 to 60000.
but not solved,

please help me on priority.